# inspec - i want to output structured data to be parsed by another function

Tags: ruby, inspec

I have a inspec test, this is great:

```
inspec exec scratchpad/profiles/forum_profile --reporter yaml
```

Trouble is I want to run this in a script and output this to an array

I cannot find the documentation that indicated what method i need to use to simulate the same

I do this

```
def my_func
  http_checker = Inspec::Runner.new()
  http_checker.add_target('scratchpad/profiles/forum_profile')
  http_checker.run
  puts http_checker.report
```

So the report method seems to give me load of the equivalent type and much more - does anyone have any documentation or advice on returning the same output as the `--reporter yaml` type response but in a script?  I want to parse the response so I can share output with another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never touched `inspec`, so take the following with a grain of salt, but according to https://github.com/inspec/inspec/blob/master/lib/inspec/runner.rb#L140, you can provide `reporter` option while instantiating the runner. Looking at https://github.com/inspec/inspec/blob/master/lib/inspec/reporters.rb#L11 I think it should be smth. like `["yaml", {}]`. So, could you please try

```
# ...
http_checker = Inspec::Runner.new(reporter: ["yaml", {}])
# ...
```

(chances are it will give you the desired output)

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly ```http_checker = Inspec::Runner.new(reporter: ["yaml"])```